# Chewed wires under subfloor

Tags: electrical, wiring, rodent

Was removing subfloor in the bathroom of my daughter's house and noticed damage to some of the wires. Looks like mice chewed on these lines. I don't see any copper so am wondering if I can wrap the damaged sections in electric tape.
Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Is that wire the service coming in from the meter, or a circuit headed out from your main panel?

Comment: I am assuming that gauge wire(8) is for a stove/dryer and not main service.  If so tape should be enough.  One problem is that it might be two hots and a neutral, used often for the now banned NEMA type 10 circuits.  If so, it is a good idea to think of upgrading that circuit to NEMA type 14, which adds a ground.  Code now allows you to just add a separate ground wire, so a new cable is not required.

Comment: I'm not sure what this particular wire serves. The house was built in the 1970s so I would not be surprised if there are aspects that no longer meet code. Thank you for the responses!

Comment: It would be grandfather into code, but because of safety concerns, it is recommended to upgrade to the safer 14-30 circuit.